# How can I write tab or enter character in SDL with TTF_RenderUTF8_Blended function?

Tags: c, utf-8, character-encoding, sdl

I would like to display a text in SDL 1.2 using UTF_8 coding. It has inside it enter and tab character. The question is,how can I achieve to display it as it appears when I use the printf function in console..

```
MY FUNCTION TO DISPLAY UTF8 STRINGS:

void displaystring(TTF_Font * font,char *text, SDL_Color color, Sint16 x, 
Sint16 y,bool center)
{
SDL_Surface *displaytext;
displaytext = TTF_RenderUTF8_Blended(font,text, color);
if(center)
    x = (WIDTH - displaytext->w)/2;

SDL_Rect towhere = { x, y,0,0 };
SDL_BlitSurface(displaytext, NULL, screen, &towhere);
SDL_Flip(screen);
}
```

And if I use it in the main:

```
MAIN:
.
.
displaystring(font60,"Éád\ngl\tő",whitec,30,30,true);
```

I would expect something like:

Éád
gl      tő

But i get:
Éád□gl□tő

What should I do to display correctly these characters?

Comment: My guess is that you will end up writing most of a parser and a renderer to simulate a console-like textoutput.

Comment: It is quite simple to split text on newlines and render each separately. Tab is harder, but basic idea may be the same - split on tab, get size of rasterised fragment with `TTF_SizeUTF8`, then select offset for next tab and start next fragment here.

Comment: So do you say I shoul change the y position of the line every time, and it will be the easiest solution?

Comment: @andris2198 someone have to, and SDL_ttf doesn't (can be easily verified by inspecting its source code). Newlines aren't hard though. Make sure you kill `\r` characters too if someone feeds windows newlines into text.